# Display photos from iPad on TV without Internet connection

Tags: ipad, appletv

Is it possible to show photos from an iPad Air on a TV without an internet connection, Wi-Fi router or 3G data plan subscription (i.e. the iPad is completely offline)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way...

If your TV supports HDMI then use a [Lightning Digital AV Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD826AM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter).

> Use the Lightning Digital AV Adapter with your iPhone, iPad, or iPod
>   with Lightning connector. The Lightning Digital AV Adapter supports
>   mirroring of what is displayed on your device screen — including apps,
>   presentations, websites, slideshows, and more — to your HDMI-equipped
>   TV, display, projector, or other compatible display in up to 1080p HD.
>
> It also outputs video content — movies, TV shows, captured video — to
>   your big screen in up to 1080p HD. Simply attach the Lightning Digital
>   AV Adapter to the Lightning connector on your device and then to your
>   TV or projector via an HDMI cable (sold separately).

You also need a [HDMI Cable](http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-Cables-Video-Interconnects-Accessories/b?ie=UTF8&node=202505011).

---

Another possible way is to use a [Lightning to VGA Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter?fnode=97).

> Use the Lightning to VGA Adapter with your iPhone, iPad, or iPod with
>   Lightning connector. The Lightning to VGA Adapter supports mirroring
>   of what is displayed on your device screen — including apps,
>   presentations, websites, slideshows, and more — to your VGA-equipped
>   TV, display, projector, or other compatible display in up to 1080p HD.
>
> It also outputs video content — movies, TV shows, captured video — to
>   your big screen in up to 1080p HD. Simply attach your Lightning to VGA
>   Adapter to the Lightning connector on your device and then to your TV
>   or projector via a VGA cable (sold separately).

You also need a [VGA Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/15782091).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can share content without an active internet connection. Once you have your Apple TV and your iOS device signed into iCloud and AirPlay works - you can disconnect both from the network and they will work ad-hoc to make a bluetooth/WiFi connection to stream content (sound and images) from the iPad to the Apple TV.

Whether you just disconnect the router and there is a local network - that will also be used for AirPlay - but an internet connection is only needed to arrange the initial account sign in one time.

Have a look at: Use AirPlay to wirelessly stream content from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289

> With AirPlay, you can stream music, photos, and videos to your Apple
>   TV, or stream music to your AirPort Express or AirPlay-enabled
>   speakers. And with AirPlay Mirroring, you can display your iOS screen
>   on your Apple TV.

Pay specific attention to the peer-to-peer AirPlay section of the above article.

Comment: While your answer make a good point, in a generalized sense, nonetheless it really doesn't answer the question within the constraints the OP stated "_without an internet connection, Wi-Fi router or 3G data plan subscription (i.e. the iPad is completely offline)_". and since the point about "_the iPad is completely offline_" is why I didn't add Apple TV to my answer.  It certainly sounds like the initial connection may not be able to be made.

Comment: @user3439894 Indeed - If it was more clear the OP's situation, I would have edited your post - but we don't really know. Yours is basically - use a cable. Mine is basically - AirPlay doesn't need internet after being set up. Both can work well in certain situations.

Comment: Agreed and if one had to purchase both the adapter and the cable, then that's making the price of the Apple TV 3 very attractive. :)

Comment: @bmike Thank you for your comments.  Both Apple TV and the Lightning adaptor seem good solutions, but given in this case there is not even going to be an initial internet connection available for set-up, I think Lightning will be the simpler solution.  If Lightning wasn't available I guess I would be looking at a temporary link-up between the iPad and my mobile phone for the initial set-up.